# Переход к структурному логированию Serilog + ELK стэк для netСore 2.2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, elasticsearch

Захотел попробовать sink Elasticsearch для Serilog и при удачном эксперименте отказаться от записи в файлы.
В приложении работают много параллельных бекграундов, которые за секунду 5-10 раз пишут инфу в лог.
Из за этого, затруднен реал тайм мониторинг работы приложения, через вывод лога в консоль.
Например, мне нужно следить только за 1 бекграундом.
Для этого решил попробовать структурное логирование, которое позволит мне применять фильтры и как раз выделять нужный мне бекграунд для мониторинга и анализа.
Текущая конфигурация Serilog логера выглядит так:

```
var loggerConf = new LoggerConfiguration()
.MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(LevelSwitch)
.MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error) 
.MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Information)

.WriteTo.File("logs/Main_Log.txt",
    LogEventLevel.Information,
    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,             //за 10 последних дней хранится Information лог (100МБ лимит размера файла)
    retainedFileCountLimit: 10,
    fileSizeLimitBytes: 100000000,                   
    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)

.WriteTo.File("logs/Error_Log.txt",                  //за 10 последних дней хранится Error лог (100МБ лимит размера файла)
    LogEventLevel.Error,
    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
    retainedFileCountLimit: 10,
    fileSizeLimitBytes: 100000000, //100МБ
    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)

.WriteTo.File("logs/Debug/Debug_Log.txt",          //За 5 последних часов переписывается Debug лог (100МБ лимит размера файла).
    LogEventLevel.Debug,
    rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Hour,
    retainedFileCountLimit: 5,
    fileSizeLimitBytes: 100000000,
    rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,                      
    shared: true);
```

Сходу переписать все логириование на структурное не получится (другие задачи стоят).
т.е. сохранять контекст как JSON (и пользоваться всем профитом по фильтрации).

```
var user = new UserMain { Id = i, Name = "Alex", Auth=true };
_logger.Information("user= {@user}", user);
```

Пока оставляю строковый вывод по всему приложению и подключаю только новый Sink - Elasticsearch.
При этом не отключая старые Sink-и для записи в файл.

Добавленная настройка sink Elasticsearch:

```
 var appName = "test123"; //Имя приложения передавать при запуске приложения
 var indexNameEs = appName + "-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}";

.WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
{
    AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
    AutoRegisterTemplateVersion = AutoRegisterTemplateVersion.ESv6,
    IndexFormat = indexNameEs,
    CustomFormatter = new ExceptionAsObjectJsonFormatter(renderMessage: true),
    MinimumLogEventLevel = LogEventLevel.Debug,

    //Обработка ошибок записи в ES
    FailureCallback = e => Console.WriteLine("ES недоступно" + e.MessageTemplate),
    EmitEventFailure = EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToSelfLog |
                       EmitEventFailureHandling.WriteToFailureSink |
                       EmitEventFailureHandling.RaiseCallback,
    FailureSink = new FileSink("./failures.txt", new JsonFormatter(), null),
})
```

ELK - запускаю в Docker с отключенным L- logstash

Вопросы:

1. Мета поля типа `_type:logevent, _id:ZNqfp2oB1j7RWDxFnY-d`, и т.д.  пишутся всегда и чтобы не засорят вывод, нужно в Kibana выбирать необходимые поля для отображения (Selected fields)?
2. Задание ограничения по времени и размеру лога?
   В старом логере я пишу логи в 3 файла ограничивая размер логов по времени и по размеру файлов (не более 100мб, если более то создается второй файл и пишется в него).
   При логировании в ELK я бы хотел настроить также.
   **Debug - за последние 5 часов, Information - за 10 последних дней**
   Это основное условие и было бы совсем круто, задать дополнительное (**если лимит > 1ГБ, то пишем циклически даже если 10 дней еще не прошло**)
3. Как лучше задавать IndexFormat?
   IndexFormat для Elasticsearch я использую 
   appName + "-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}"
   на каждые сутки создается новый индекс в БД.
   Если у меня будет работать ограничение по кол-ву дней (из вопроса 2) то что будет происходить с устаревшими индексами? 
   По идее должно хранится 10 дней, т.е. 10 последних индексов, наиболее старые автоматом удаляются, как происходит с файлами.
   и может лучше создавать индекс на месяц -  {0:yyyy.MM}?

Comment: 1. Мета поля не фильтруются даже с помощью excludes 2. Можно писать в 2 индекса и удалять curator либо удалять данные самостоятельно https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/docs-delete-by-query.html но это делать довольно странно при логировании. 3. На ваше усмотрение, все равно временем жизни индексов вы управляете самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо, можно поподробнее по пункту 2 расписать и  Что такое curator? Было бы достаточно просто ограничение на размер по 1 индексу. например 10Гб места для моего сервиса циклически перезаписываются. Какое ограничение Serilog выставляет по умолчанию я не нашел (ограничение на файлы 30 дней).